# Проверка view на вход в зону другого view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

На данный момент я делаю приложение, в котором нужно случайно сгенерировать координаты view из кода, а затем разместить этот view на экране. Но из-за того, что координаты генерируются случайно, в большинстве случаев view "залезает" на второй view.

**Конкретный вопрос:**
Как и где лучше организовать проверку на вход в зону другого view

**Код генерирования случайных координат:**

```
 variableOne.x = ((portalX - 200).toInt()..portalX.toInt()).random().toFloat()
 variableOne.y = ((portalY - 150).toInt()..(portalY + 150).toInt()).random().toFloat()
```

**Переменные в коде:**

*variableOne* - объект, для которого нужно сгенерировать координаты

*portalX* и *portalY* - переменные, хранящие координаты view, рядом с которым нужно  создать 2 других view

**P.s** Пытался гуглить по вопросу, но ничего не нашёл. Уже дня 2 над ним думаю

Comment: Забыл указать в вопросе, что язык - Kotlin

Comment: По идее вам надо хранить массив координат всех добавленных вьюх. При генерации новой можно проверить не пересекается ли к-л её сторона с к-л стороной любой другой вьюхи. Ну и сделать что-то в этом случае. И только потом вьюху добавлять. Или сохранять диапазоны занятых координат и в процесс генерации встроить запрет на эти диапазоны. Возможно, также, в математике есть к-л формула, процесс упрощающая, но мне такая неизвестна.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую